# Error running JavaFx 13 on IntelliJ (and yes, thoroughly I have followed the tutorial)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, intellij-14

First time with JavaFx. To begin with, I've made sure that my version of Java is, indeed, Java 13: Screenshot:

[image: proof from terminal]

And, I've followed all the directions on the JavaFx tutorials: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#introduction

I've spent so many hours on this issue. I found similar problems, but the closest "solution" to my problem assumed that the VM customization was put in verbatim, but I have made sure to use the *correct path*. I have tried the tutorials for both modular and non-modular applications. I have customized everything, for the project itself to Appearance and Behavior preferences. I downloaded the separate JavaFx 13 file from via Gluon and made sure I was able to access them (I have a Mac, so this required a security override).

I have gone so far as to uninstall all Java and JavaFx libraries from my computer and reinstalled them.

After trying what seems to be everything, I have the same error :(

Screenshot:

[image: Exception in Application start method]

Otherwise, if I try to toggle some, I'll get the classic (but dreaded) result:

"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module JavaFxProject not found"

Does anybody have some insight into this? I'd love to find out it was a tiny bug that I could easily eliminate, even though I've already spent so many hours trying to solve this problem myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the actual command line generated by IntelliJ and verified that all javafx jars are actually on the module path and not on the classpath?

Comment: Include `javafx.fxml` in the `--add-modules` argument.

Comment: no screenshots please, instead c&p code/error messages

Comment: your setup is broken somehow .. nothing we can do from here. First try to run the example (stick to either non/modular, doesn't  matter which - just _do not_ randomly mix options - until you can run it from the command line. Then configure your IDE as needed and triple check all context. Eventually, you'll succeed :)

Comment: @mipa I haven't tried this, or at least I'm not sure what you mean. How is it done, and is there a site wehre I can read more about it?

ps: sorry to be so delayed in my response. The reason was, I had to drive from my home in Salt Lake to Chicago yesterday. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @Slaw Unfortunately, I did this. In my non-module version, it was included in the VM line, according to the JavaFx setup tutorial. I also tried, with a separate file, to do this in an actual module info file.

Comment: @keopatra thanks! I'll try to do that in the future (second? post ever). For this particular post, is there any information I left out that you think would have been helpful?

Comment: If you have a module-info file then you need a `requires javafx.fxml` directive in said file. Anyway, the error says the `javafx.fxml` module is being used from the classpath instead of the modulepath; if you _don't_ have a module-info file then the fix is to include `javafx.fxml` in the `--add-modules` argument. If that isn't working then, assuming it's not simply a problem with how you configured the arguments in your IDE, I honestly don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @abelllizard I can't tell you how to show the actual command line used by IntelliJ to execute your program because I don't use IntelliJ but maybe someone else here knows or google it.